# How to calculate age in rails admin as an export value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, export, rails-admin

I want to calculate the `age` using `dob` in `rails_admin` and pass it in export action as an output. Is there any way ?

I have the function :

```
def age(dob)
  now = Time.now.utc.to_date
  dob = DateTime.parse(dob)
  age = now.year - dob.year - ((now.month > dob.month || (now.month == dob.month && now.day >= dob.day)) ? 0 : 1)
  return age
end
```

But I don't know where to require it in rails_admin!

```
export do
  field :dob, :datetime do
    label "Age"
     export_value do
        dob(value) if value 
     end
   end
end
```

but this is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like below :

```
export do
  field :dob, :datetime do
    label "Age"
    export_value do
       ((Time.now - value.dob.to_time)/(60*60*24*365)).floor if value
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: That's correct Thank you @Kalpeshdav but there is a minor bug in value.dob it should be just value in line 5